# Django list_editable() can not display primary key value

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I try to display different fields in Django admin page and find to options to display details in the page. I am sure that `list_display_links` works,but I get error when I try `list_editable`. Can someone points out the reason of error?

```
class SaleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ["pk","product_id","old_price","new_price","discount_start","discount_end","store_id","created"]
    list_display = ["pk","product_id","old_price","new_price","discount_start","discount_end","store_id","created"]
    list_display_links = ["pk","product_id","old_price","new_price","discount_start","discount_end","store_id","created"]

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
    def store_id(self, instance):
        return instance.store_id.id

    def product_id(self, instance):
        return instance.product_id.name
```

Error:

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'dataInfo.admin.SaleAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to 'pk', which is not an attribute of 'dataInfo.Sale'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message complains about this part

```
list_editable = ["pk", "product_id","old_price", ...
```

Change it to "id".

```
list_editable = ["id", "product_id","old_price", ...
```

Better yet, remove `pk`/`id` from that list, because you most likely do not want to edit the primary key.